# Using str_replace to format a link into an image with embeded hyperlink

Tags: php

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way.  I would like to take a simple link, like this;

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo`

and turn it into

`<a href= 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/examplevideo' target=_blank><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/examplevideo/0.jpg' width='536' border='1'></a>`

In the past, I've been able to change links by using a str_replace, which was very straightforward since you would pull out one pattern and just replace it with another.  But, in this case, the pattern that's being kept shows up twice in the output.  Is a str_replace the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one simple way to do it...

```
// $video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo";
$videoId = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "", $video_url);
enter code here
$videoLink = "<a href= 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/$videoId' target=_blank><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$videoId/0.jpg' width='536' border='1'></a>"
```

Of course, if your URL is more complex (e.g. ?v=abc&t=123) then this won't work, and you would have to parse the URL more like a URL (i.e. not using str_replace).

Comment: Interesting, so your created a variable with what was left over from the str_replace, then you applied it to a new variable.  Thanks, Hamza.

Comment: @Kimomaru: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) to get the video ID, and then use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) to build the embed code.

I've made a small function:

```
function getEmbedded($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $parsed = parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
    $result = sprintf("<a href= 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/%s' 
        target=_blank><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/0.jpg' 
        width='536' border='1'></a>", $params['v'],$params['v']);
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getEmbedded($url);
```

This is more efficient than using `str_replace()` and works even when there are additional query parameters in the video URL.